# Need help to install curses for python 3.x with pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, python-curses

Im trying to install curses for windows python 3.x with pycharm. i installed windows curses via pip. but if i import it, theres just message saying no module found.

In terminal/cmd

python -m pip install windows-curses

Requirement already satisfied

then if i type...

```
c:/.../.../python
import curses
curses.initscr()
```

i get a blank screen

but importing in python console or as script is not possible. no module found.
Any advises to globaly use import and not just in terminal/cmd.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Pycharm>Settings>Project Interpreter. Click on the plus icon at the top right.In search type curses or any library which you want to install. Don't forget to check the 'Install to user's site package directory' box.

Comment: Now it works, thank you very much. Had to add one more thing. In Run/Edit Configurations.... i selected my file.py and checked "Emulate Terminal in Output Console".